# Find the equation of a line intersecting a parabola

Tags: calculus, derivatives, systems-of-equations, quadratics

Okay here's the question:

Consider the parabola *P* of equation $y=x^2$, and the line $L$ of equation $y=x+6$. Let $P(x_p,y_p)$ be a point on the arc of the parabola P below L. Let A and B be the points of intersection of $P$ and $L$.

a) Find an equation of the line $L_p$ passing through $P$ which is perpendicular to $L$.

I'm having a really hard time finding the equation for the line $L_p$ that passes through the parabola $y=x^2$.
$$$$
[image: 1]

I know that the slope is -1 which leaves me with $L_p = -x + b$.

However, i'm having trouble solving for $b$. I need a coordinate point on the graph of $L_p$ or some type of relationship to find $b$, and i cant figure out a way to work around it.

Please help. I've spent too long on this and my head hurts.

Comment: Please try to make your post self-contained, so that even if your link expires, we may still see the question. The question is not clear from your image either. You can fix this with an edit.

Comment: @YiFan Thanks, I've now put the question in as text. Stack wont let me insert an image within the body of the text - I guess i'm not "experienced enough yet. The image is just the diagram I've drew.

Comment: @ChristopherMarley thank you!! that looks better

Comment: Are you familiar with [point-slope form](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/two-var-linear-equations/point-slope/a/point-slope-form-review)?

Comment: Are there any conditions on the point $(x_p, y_p)$ (other than being on the parabola)? Your diagram seems to imply that $A$ has the same $y$-coordinate but there is no mention of that in the statement of the problem. If there isn't, then Christopher Marley's answer is the best one can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is right so far, but I wouldn't turn straight to slope-intercept form.

We know that the slope of $L_p$ is -1, and it passes through a point on the parabola. This point $P$ you say has coordinates $(x_p, y_p)$. Because $y=x^2$, this point can be rewritten as $(x_p, x_p^2)$.

Then, we'll turn to point-slope form, i.e. $y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$.

$$y-x_p^2=(-1)(x-x_p)$$
$$y=-x+x_p+x_p^2$$

Answer (score 0):

You have a point $p = (x_p,y_p)$, and a slope $m$. Then, the equation of the line is given in the point-slope form

$$ y-y_p = m(x-x_p) $$

Since the line $L$ has a slope of $1$, the line perpendicular has a slope of $-1$, so we must have $m=-1$ (you knew this already). The point is not chosen, but we know it is below the line, which is strictly between the points $a = (x_a,y_a)$ and $b = (x_b,y_b)$. So, $x_a < x_p < x_b$, and since $p$ is on the parabola $y=x^2$, $y_p^2 = x_p^2$. Thus, we have the line

$$ y - x_p^2 = -(x - x_p) \text{ for } x_a < x_p < x_b $$

Now, the points $x_a$ and $x_b$ are the $x$-values of the intersections of $y=x^2$ and $y = x+6$, i.e. solutions to the equation $x^2 = x+6$. The solutions to this equation are $x=-2,3$. Since $a$ is the further left point, we have $x_a = -2$ and $x_b = 3$. Thus, the equation for the perpendicular line is

$$ y - x_p^2 = -(x - x_p) \text{ for } -2 < x_p < 3 $$

If you want to rearrange it, you can write the slope-intercept form

$$ y = -x + (x_p+x_p^2) \text{ or } y = -x+x_p(1+x_p) \text{ for } -2 < x_p < 3  $$